# Как разбить React.AspNet компоненты в ASP.NET core

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core

На сайте metanit есть стать по использованию React.Js в ASP.NET Core. Она в общем мне понравилась кроме того что все компоненты пишутся в одном файле.
Я пытался использовать import/export, но я почему то не могу его использовать:Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module, testComponent.jsx:6 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'.

Мне нужен способ разбить компоненты по отдельным файлам.

app.jsx

```js
import { Hello } from './components/testComponent';

class Form extends React.Component {
   render() {
    return (
          <Hello />
    );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
   <Form />,
   document.getElementById("content")
);
```

testComponent.jsx

```js
export class Hello extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <h1>Привет, Eugene</h1>;
    }
}
```

Comment: https://metanit.com/sharp/aspnet5/25.2.php

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался. Теги  надо добавить type="module" для работы import/export.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]